# Python Script unable to save Connector - Enterprise Architect

Tags: javascript, python, enterprise-architect

I'm trying to add new Connectors to an EA model using Python. Unfortunately, when my script runs, it does not add the Connector. The same script written in Javascript, via the EA Javascript console, is able to add the Connector.

What's odd is the Python script doesn't fail. It behaves like it added the Connector. If I refresh the elements being connected, it appears the Connector is there. I can even get a ConnectorID from the Python console.

PYTHON:

```py
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import os

ea = Dispatch("EA.App")
rep = ea.Repository
path = os.path.normpath("C:/temp/eaFile.eap")

e1 = rep.GetElementByID(121228)
e2 = rep.GetElementByID(120663)
newCon = e1.Connectors.AddNew("","Association")
newCon.ClientID = e1.ElementID
newCon.SupplierID = e2.ElementID
newCon.Update()
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```js
e1 = Repository.GetElementByID(121228);
e2 = Repository.GetElementByID(120663);
newCon = e1.Connectors.AddNew("", "Association");
newCon.ClientID = e1.ElementID;
newCon.SupplierID = e2.ElementID;
newCon.Update();
```

I expect the Connector to be visible as a link on the Element within Enterprise Architect - I'm not able to find it when run from Python, I am able to find it when run from Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out.
The main problem was that I was missing the following line after defining my path:

```
rep.OpenFile(path)
```

Because of that it wouldn't connect. Must've lost this line while troubleshooting this script.

I think a secondary issue was that my Python console was still open from previous sessions, and I had multiple EA models open, so there was some oddity to how EA was behaving with the connection to the desired model (like I said, I was getting feedback in the script as if I was connected).

I think the biggest give away here is that EA likes to Reload the Project every time I successfully run a python script against the Repository, closing all open windows in the app (probably to pickup changes). If EA's not throwing away your work, you're doing something wrong!

Answer (score 2):

For some strange reason you need to call update without braces.

```
e1 = rep.getelementbyguid("{B2F19D81-1475-41f2-BABD-AA66E11FAE10}")
e2 = rep.getelementbyguid("{86DFDB7C-0838-47eb-8402-384701170C34}")
con = e1.connectors.addnew("", "Dependency")
con.supplierId = e2.elementId
con.update
```

worked for me. I never investigated why, I'm just used to the EA way...

N.B. The connector already has `clientId` set, so you don't need that assignment.

---

Here's an excerpt of my wrapper class

```
import win32com.client
from singleton import Singleton
import errorlogger
import eacodes
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re
import os

@Singleton
class Repository:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            app = win32com.client.GetActiveObject("EA.App")
            self.eaRep = app.Repository
            models = self.eaRep.models
            done = True
        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
            done = False
        if not done:
            logger = errorlogger.ErrorLogger.Instance()
            logger._fatal("Can not find a running EA instance")

        self.base = self.eaRep.connectionstring
        if os.path.exists(self.base):
            path, self.base = os.path.splitext(self.base.lower())
        else:
            self.base = "server"
        self.wildcard = "%" if self.base == ".eap" else "*"

    def query(self, sql):
        root = ET.fromstring(self.eaRep.SQLQuery (sql))
        data = root.getchildren()
        if len(data) == 0: return []
        ds = data[0][0]
        rows = []
        for row in ds:
            cols = []
            for col in row.getchildren(): cols.append(col.text)
            rows.append(cols)
        return rows
```

It's cut from the whole and misses parts but you can take it as start. Singleton can be found somewhere here on SO (IIRC). Usage:

```
rep = Repository.Instance()
e = rep.getElementByGuid("{B2F19D81-1475-41f2-BABD-AA66E11FAE10}")
print e.name
for row in rep.query("SELECT name FROM t_object"):
    print row[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. I think I figured it out - I forgot the line:
rep.OpenFile(path)
while troubleshooting.

It looks like con.update and con.update() are both working for me now.
Thank you for pointing out the extra clientId.

Comment: Oops. That was an obvious one. Actually I use a wrapper class for repository which opens a running instance and offers a couple of extras.

Comment: sounds exciting, care to shed some light on the wrapper you used?